# domain.com/username mod rewrite in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm new to mode rewrite thing. Started off with codeigniter a couple of days back and trying to get a hand at it. I'm developing a website which needs domain.com/USERNAME for better SEO results. But I'm unable to figure out as to what mod rewrite I should write to achieve this. I already have removed the index.php entry in config and my base url is `http://127.0.0.1/myproject/`. (I'm using XAMPP)
So I have to search for username in this format

`http://127.0.0.1/myproject/USERNAME`

and return the corresponding page. My current mod rewrite file goes as follows :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: You should be looking at routing http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html , not mod_rewrite for this task.

Comment: Thank you for replying. How can I route any request (domain.com/anyrequest) exckuding the controllers which I use. Because default controller is main and I dun want domain.com/main or any other controller to be routed as a username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://daparky.com/codeigniter-vanity-username-personalised-urls/

this should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.Tried it. I'm not sure why it isn't working. Logically things seem correct. I added the MVC code from there and the following username route corresponding to the controller that I have created ofcourse `$route['([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)'] = 'userpages/check/$1';
`

Comment: Got it working. Needed a better regular expression. Thank you!

Comment: @harsh8888 I know you did this very long before but can you help be to do the same for me? Just a brief description to have a URL like example.com/username.